# Receiving calls for subaccounts using twilio

Tags: twilio

I have a little trouble. I have twilio application which allow to create subaccounts, purchase phone numbers and other for my customers. I need to add possibility for receiving and making calls by my customers. 
There are a lot of documentation and guides at http://twilio.com but I can't find example how could I bind  and receive calls for subaccount's phone numbers in my application. There are examples for master account only. Can you give me example of code or links where such examples placed?

Regards.

Comment: Hello Zed. I am also building up a app that have sub users. Can u please tell me how are you managing the sub users . Actually i am also building a same application but in mine the user will himself buy a twillio number and then all the calls and messges will process through the users personal number . I need some guidance . Please help ! Will be really very thankful to you.

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to use the Account Sid and Auth Token of the [subaccount](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/subaccounts) in the same way as you use your parent account's sid and token. Just drop them into the helper library and then make requests in the same way.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Yes, I found the solution myself.

Comment: Yes. By only using Account Sid and Auth Token of the subaccount will work. You can verify this by viewing the logs in subaccount. That means, for subaccount, logs will be generated in their own account. You can switch between parent account and subaccount anytime.

Comment: @RakeshPatel  Sir i am building up an application that basically have the calling feature using twilio . Everything is good but i need a functionality that the user himself buys a twilio number and then all the calls will process through that number. Need guidance ! Please help.